# GitHub and Travis CI - How to fail build when tests fail

Tags: scala, github, travis-ci

I have a Scala project on GitHub and I use the Travis CI to build it and show the resulting badge on the project home in GitHub. I started to write unit tests and I realized that during one of my commit, some tests failed. But the travis build shows that the build passes.

I know that I should be using some kind of hook to check for tests failures and correspondingly fail my build. But I just don't know what the correct command for that is? I could not as well infer this from any documentation.

Here is my travis.yml file:

```
language: scala

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

scala:
  - 2.11.7

script:
  - sbt clean coverage test coverageReport

after_success:
  - bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)
```

What hook should I add here so that the build fails as soon as one of my unit test fails?

Comment: what is the return code you are getting for the command `sbt clean coverage test coverageReport`?. if one of the test fails the return code is usually 1 which should fail your build.

Comment: 1591The command "sbt clean coverage test coverageReport" exited with 1