# Build does not fail when tests fail

Tags: maven, github, travis-ci

I'm using maven to execute my tests and they clearly fail. Even the log in travis-ci tells me this:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

Still the build passes, both the badge and checks on pull requests.

How can I fix this?

Same problem as this guy:
[GitHub and Travis CI - How to fail build when tests fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44275940/github-and-travis-ci-how-to-fail-build-when-tests-fail)

Comment: Can you provide a link to a build log where this happens?